# Incorrent Python package deployed in Azure functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-python-sdk

I have a Azure Functions application and it works locally on Windows machine.
The application is deployed on Linux, Python 3.9

`failed: AttributeError: module 'rlp' has no attribute 'Serializable'`

Locally I see this for package rlp

```
>>> dir(rlp) ['DecodingError', 'DeserializationError', 'EncodingError', 'LazyList', 'RLPException', 'Serializable', 'SerializationError', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'atomic', 'codec', 'decode', 'decode_lazy', 'encode', 'exceptions', 'infer_sedes', 'lazy', 'peek', 'sedes', 'utils']
```

And print from deployed function shows this,

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'decode', 'encode', 'rlp']
```

I tried different versions but the results are same, at the moment using rlp==2.0.1 as part of requirements.txt

deployed `rlp` package doesn't have require attributes.

Comment: Similar Thread : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/923732/incorrect-python-package-being-used.html

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can try is to set the environment variable PYTHON_ISOLATE_WORKER_DEPENDENCIES to '1' - that will ensure that your Azure function doesn't use the version of packages that were already installed by Azure.